# Reading files from a directory inside a meteor app

Tags: node.js, meteor

How can i read the public directory in a meteor application inside my /server path.

I tried using the native `'fs'` package but i keep getting a file/directory not found error.

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
var files = fs.readdirSync('/public/soundfiles/');
```

Has anyone used the filesystem package to read static files inside a meteor application?

Comment: You are using an absolute path `'/'` . Try using a relative one `'./public/soundfiles/'` or `'public/soundfiles/'`

Comment: Tried all relative paths - for some reason fs starts reading from my packages directory. For example, if i pass `.` and i output `files`, i get all the files in my packages directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access files without the "/public" part. In a running Meteor app, the `public` directory becomes your root, and everything that is located at `/public/whatever` can be accessed at `/whatever`.

Additionally, if you're playing around with files, you might find these useful:

- [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)
- [CollectionFS](https://github.com/raix/Meteor-CollectionFS)

Answer (score 6):

I learned that it is best to upload files in your private folder if you are not displaying them outside.
In my case I need to store XML uploads and process them.
At first I wrote the XML into the public folder but that would trigger a reload.
Then I renamed the the upload folder to /public/.#uploads which would stop the reload of Meteor, but then again...it completely ignored that folder during build and the uploaded folder would not exist in the build (throw ENOENT error during read).

So I figured out it is best to put the files in /private/files and then reading goes as follows:

`result = fs.readdirSync('assets/app/files')`

Everything in the private folder will be moved to the Assets folder where during runtime there is an APP folder available (you do not see that in your build folder structure).

It helps to just simple dump `result = fs.readdirSync('.')` to see what folder you in and look through the structure.

***UPDATE*****
Locally putting files in `private` folder still triggered meteor rebuild/update (perhaps not in production..) so I found another solution using the UploadServer just to define the upload directory:
https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads

Answer (score 4):

This works for me in Meteor 1.0:

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs')
var xsd = fs.readFileSync(process.cwd().split('.meteor')[0] + 'server/company.xsd', 'utf8')
```

Comment: works on local but fails on a production build, have you used this in a production build?

Comment: Due to lack of devs and slow compiling on Windows, all Meteor projects were cancelled here last year, so i forgot.

Comment: @chulian This solution works typically for compilation. Probably this was used in a Package. It does not work in production since the paths are changed, same story as described in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

This is no longer true. For Meteor 0.8, the folder "../client/app" is public. Thus, use fs.readdirSync('../client/app') to get files and folders in public.

Source: personal experience and https://stackoverflow.com/a/18405793

Comment: Using Meteor 1.0.1.  I had to use this: fs.createReadStream("../../../../../public/data");  Seems crazy I know but that is what worked for me

Answer (score 2):

For meteor 1.0.2 public is /web.browser/app/
Checked by entering .meteor dir
Total path in linux /home/user/your_app_name/.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/app/
And to get to root is `process.env.PWD or process.cwd().
Im not sure if its work deployed.

```
_meteor_bootstrap_.serverDir +'/assets/app'
```

This is path to private folder.

Comment: 1.0 says `ReferenceError: _meteor_bootstrap_ is not defined.`

Answer (score 1):

For Meteor 1.4, use server Assets.
See the official docs on Assets
http://docs.meteor.com/api/assets.html

Comment: The problem is that assets is for plain text files, but I want to read the list of jsx files in a folder to create the react router paths

Answer (score 0):

On the server you can use `fs` to access any part of the meteor directory tree, not just `/public`, for example

```
import fs from 'fs';
const rd = process.env.PWD;
const obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${rd}/private/file.json`));
```

would read and parse a json file located at `private/file.json` under your meteor app directory root.