# meteor: How to list files and directories from the project root path?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm using Meteor 1.0.2.1 and I noticed that working with the filesystem is not as easy as I tought :p

I ended up installing the peerlibrary:fs package (https://atmospherejs.com/peerlibrary/fs) so that I now have access to the node.js "fs" module and now I'm trying to list the content of the public folder but as mentioned here:

[Reading files from a directory inside a meteor app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762983/reading-files-from-a-directory-inside-a-meteor-app#comment43597100_22749503)

the path now (with version 1) seems to be '../../../../../public'

`var files = fs.readdirSync('../../../../../public');`

But I assume this to be wrong.

Is there an alias to the project root folder?
Is it ok to use the peerlibrary:fs for this?

Thanks.

Comment: you can try to use process.env.PWD, fs.readdirSync(process.env.PWD + '/public');

Comment: Hi @Alexander, thanks for your answer. If I'm right, the only downside is that relying on the environment variable, you could get a different result. For example if you run "meteor run" from /my/project/server you get the latter instead of just /my/project

Answer (score 0):

console.log of  `_meteor_bootstrap_` says(I removed personal content)

```
    { startupHooks: 
   [ [Function],      [Function],
      [Function],      [Function],
      [Function],
      [Function],
      [Function],
      [Function],
      [Function] ],
   serverDir: 'my_path_to_serverDir',
   configJson: 
    { meteorRelease: 'METEOR@1.0.2',
      clientPaths: { 'web.browser': '../web.browser/program.json' } } }
=> Started your app.
```

I did checked program.json in /home/user/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/program.json 
Part of it looks like that(I changed some personal data)

```
{
  "path": "app/pathToImage/image.png",
  "where": "client",
  "type": "asset",
  "cacheable": false,
  "url": "/pathToimage/image.png",
  "size": someSize,
  "hash": "someHash"
},
```

On that i state there is no public folder in deployed state but you can get paths from program.json file and `_meteor_bootstrap_.configJson.clientPaths` gives object with path to it wich looks like this(paste from console.log):
`{ 'web.browser': '../web.browser/program.json' }`

Comment: There is `__meteor_bootstrap__.serverDir` which returns /my/project/.meteor/local/build/programs/server therefore I could use the ".meteor" string to just take everything before it, but not sure how solid this would be.