# File path in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm having trouble identifying the path to a file in the public directory c:\TEMP\todos\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\public\main.py. Meteor complains the file or directory doesn't exist. Already searched the other postings about the similar issue (e.g., [Reading files from a directory inside a meteor app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762983/reading-files-from-a-directory-inside-a-meteor-app)) but didn't help.

Here is the error message.

```
=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
=> Modified -- restarting.
=> Meteor server restarted
W20151206-04:05:57.893(-5)? (STDERR) Error inside the Async.runSync: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'c:\TEMP\todos\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\public'
```

Client code

```
Meteor.call('runPython', function(err, response) {
    if(err){

    } else {
        console.log(response);
    }
})
```

Server code

```
Meteor.startup( function (){
    Meteor.methods({
        runPython: function (){
            var PythonShell = Meteor.npmRequire('python-shell');
            var fs = Meteor.npmRequire('fs');

            var runPython = Async.runSync(function (done){
                var files = fs.readdirSync('./public/');

//   PythonShell.run('main.py', function ... was tried first but Meteor complained that "main.py doesn't exist". So below is a different attempt.

                var py = _(files).reject(function(fileName){
                    return fileName.indexOf('.py') <0;
                })

            PythonShell.run(py, function (err) {
// PythonShell.run(path.join(py,"main.py") ... was also tried but resulted in the same error
                if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('script running failed');
                });
        })

        return "Success";
    }
})
})
```

Comment: FYI: `public` should be at the root of your Meteor app, not under `server`. From the client side the `public` directory will resolve to `/`, not `/public`

Answer (score 0):

All files inside the `public` folder should be read using `'/'`:

```
var files = fs.readdirSync('/');
```

More here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp

For server-side only (might be your case and probably a better solution) you can put everything under the `private/` folder and access them by using the **Assets API**: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/assets_getText

Comment: Although your answer didn't solve my problem, it's still very helpful information. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly I was overthinking it. Specifying a full path to the file was all I needed to do.

```
PythonShell.run('c:\\project\\public\\main.py', function ...
```

Comment: That will not work if you deploy your code somewhere else, will it?

Comment: I guess it depends on where it is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

If your application allows moving the Python script to `/private` instead of `/public`, you can take advantage of Meteor's [Assets](http://docs.meteor.com/api/assets.html):

> `Assets` allows server code in a Meteor application to access static server assets, which are located in the private subdirectory of an application’s tree. Assets are not processed as source files and are copied directly into your application’s bundle.

e.g. If you move your script to `/private/scripts/script.py` you can generate the absolute path the [Meteor way](http://docs.meteor.com/api/assets.html#Assets-absoluteFilePath) by doing `Assets.absoluteFilePath('scripts/script.py')`.